# Run ffmpeg on windows - real-time buffer [USB Camera] [video input] too full or near too full frame dropped

Tags: ffmpeg

I got successed on macos and linux with :

Linux :

```
ffmpeg \
    -f v4l2 \
    -framerate 25 -video_size 640x480 -i /dev/video0 \
    -f mpegts \
    -codec:v mpeg1video -s 640x480 -b:v 1000k -bf 0 \
    http://localhost:8081/supersecret
```

MacOS test:

```
  ffmpeg -f avfoundation -framerate 30 -video_size 640x480 \
  -i "0" -f mpegts -codec:v mpeg2video -s 640x480 -b:v 1000k \
  -bf 0 http://localhost:8081/supersecret
```

I already installed ffmpeg on windows a just need correct command.

My error log is :

> `/dev/video0: No such file or directory`

***Update :***

After `ffmpeg -list_devices true -f dshow -i dummy` i got :

```
...
[dshow @ 000001985949ce80] DirectShow video devices (some may be both video and audio devices)
[dshow @ 000001985949ce80]  "USB Camera"
[dshow @ 000001985949ce80]     Alternative name "@device_pnp_\\?\usb#vid_0c45&pid_6340&mi_00#6&313cdc8e&0&0000#{65e8773d-8f56-11d0-a3b9-00a0c9223196}\global"
...
```

Than i try to run my server with:

```
ffmpeg -f dshow -i video="USB Camera"  -framerate 30 -video_size 640x480 -f mpegts -codec:v mpeg2video -s 640x480 -b:v 1000k -bf 0 http://localhost:8081/supersecret
```

And i catch this log:

```
Input #0, dshow, from 'video=USB Camera':
  Duration: N/A, start: 27271.559000, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0: Video: rawvideo (YUY2 / 0x32595559), yuyv422, 640x480, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 10000k tbn, 10000k tbc
[dshow @ 0000022a4be9f0c0] real-time buffer [USB Camera] [video input] too full or near too full (101% of size: 3041280 [rtbufsize parameter])! frame dropped!
    Last message repeated 173 times
[tcp @ 0000022a4beae340] Connection to tcp://localhost:8081 failed: Error number -138 occurred
http://localhost:8081/supersecret: Unknown error
[dshow @ 0000022a4be9f0c0] real-time buffer [USB Camera] [video input] too full or near too full (101% of size: 3041280 [rtbufsize parameter])! frame dropped!
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typically on windows you would use DirectShow for input.

List devices

- `ffmpeg -list_devices true -f dshow -i dummy`

Example capture

- `ffmpeg -f dshow -i video="Integrated Camera" etc...`

Docs:

- https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/DirectShow

---

Note that this question is probably considered off-topic for StackOverflow.  It would be better on https://superuser.com/. Details: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/168740/are-ffmpeg-questions-really-off-topic

Comment: Thnks i moved from dead point, i updated question. If you have some suggesiton for updated question it will be nice Mr. @kaliatech

Comment: You should consider posting this as a new question on SuperUser.com.  Regarding your new error, it could be a number of things, but I think usually means your system is not able to keep up while transcoding the incoming stream for real-time output. You might try increasing the rtbuffer size with `-rtbufsize 256M`, but it could be many other things too.  Again, consider posting as a new question.